# Can Encrypted external drive encrypted on/by ubuntu work with Windows?

Tags: windows, 15.04, encryption, disk-utility

I was thinking of encrypting my drive but before that I have to make sure that It will work with Windows because in case I am out of options I have to choose windows to recover data.
I am talking about encrypting drive with `Crypt setup`

Also I would like to know if there are any other(other than cryptsetup) options for external disk encryption with better encryption standards.

Please do not add Truecrypt to your answer because of [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58940/is-truecrypt-not-secure-now-and-should-i-stop-using-it)

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called LibreCrypt[1] that works in windows and can open LUKS based encrypted volumes created by cryptsetup.

There is nice cryptsetup frond end called zuluCrypt[2] you can use to create LUKS volumes in ubuntu.Scroll down the page to see binary package for ubuntu.

ps:
cryptsetup by default creates LUKS based encrypted volumes,

[1] https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt

[2] http://mhogomchungu.github.io/zuluCrypt/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any tool that can setup LUKS drive in Windows. 
However, there is a tool called TrueCrypt that works equally slow both in Linux and Windows.

Comment: TrueCrypt is obsolete it is not updated now Bitlocker is used with windows only. see this http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It is obsolete, but it does not mean it disappeared in a whiff of magic smoke.